# Difference between new Date() and new Date(val)

Tags: javascript, date

In console, if I type this code:

```
var Time = new Date();
```

Then output is:

> Time = Wed Sep 13 2017 13:17:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

And with this code:

```
var Time1 = new Date(val);  // value should be number
```

Then output is:

> Time1 = Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

For all `val`, `Time1` is same;

What does `new Date(val)` mean?

Comment: who told that val should be number? you can give a date.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: You could answer that yourself, **by reading the manual**: _"Integer value representing **the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC**, with leap seconds ignored (Unix Epoch; but consider that most Unix time stamp functions count in seconds)."_

Comment: programming 101: Read documentation first, ask questions later

Comment: "*For all val, Time1 is same*" no, it isn't. But there are 86,400,000 milliseconds in a 24 hour day, so you need a big number of them to change the date.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comment, Actually it was my mistake to post question without investigating deep about Date. I regret for my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var d = new Date(86400000);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

when you pass number in milliseconds in new Date () it will be added to the default time value

Comment: Fri Jan 02 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530